# AND Condition on belongsToMany association SEQUELIZE

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I'm using Sequelize and I have 2 models (Article and Tag) associated with belongsToMany through another model called ArticleTags.

I want to fetch all the Articles that have one Tag with id=1 AND one Tag with id=2.

I've tried multiple solutions, but it always fetches the Articles that have one Tag with id=1 OR one Tag with id=2.

This is the code I have as of now:

```js
let articles = await Article.findAll({
    limit: limit, 
    offset: offset, 
    subQuery: false,
    where:[ {"$Tags.id$": {1,2} }]


    include:{
        model: Tag, 
        required: false
    }, 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your where clause to this:

```js
where: {
  "$Tags.id$": {
    [Op.and]: [1, 2]
  }
}
// SELECT * FROM articles WHERE $Tags.id$ = 1 AND $Tags.id$ = 2
```

This should work else have another look at the [docs for applying where clauses](https://sequelize.org/v7/manual/model-querying-basics.html#applying-where-clauses)

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the reply but I think this doesn't work.

Comment: It returns an empty list, and I assume it checks for the same Tag if the id = 1 AND id = 2, which will be false.

Comment: This is the raq SQL of the change you've suggested:

Comment: SELECT `Article`.`id`, `Tags`.`id` AS `Tags.id`, `Tags`.`text` AS `Tags.text`, `Tags->ArticleTag`.`ArticleId` AS `Tags.ArticleTag.ArticleId`, `Tags->ArticleTag`.`TagId` AS `Tags.ArticleTag.TagId` FROM `Articles` AS `Article` LEFT OUTER JOIN ( `ArticleTags` AS `Tags->ArticleTag` INNER JOIN `Tags` AS `Tags` ON `Tags`.`id` = `Tags->ArticleTag`.`TagId`) ON `Article`.`id` = `Tags->ArticleTag`.`ArticleId` WHERE ((`Tags`.`id` = 1 AND `Tags`.`id` = 2))

Comment: i still haven't been able to figure it out, one year later haha